# Place plotline above one series, but below another series

Tags: highcharts

I have two series - one is an arearange, the other is a line. I'd like to show a plotline above the arearange, but below the line; I can't figure out how to do this.

A live example is at http://1212.one/ - click the name of a team to show the chart. I'd like the "PLAYOFFS" plotline to show above the grey arearange but stay below the line.

Is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue relates to the fact that all series are drawn within the same group, and therefore have the same z-index related to other groups. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3321) for discussion and code examples.

See [this one example solution](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/r3Lzjjz6/1/), proposed by Torstein Hønsi (Highcharts creator). I've made a modified, [minimal, reproducible example here](https://jsfiddle.net/rhs3w172/):

```
/**
 * Plugin to allow plot band Z indexes in between series
 */
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.PlotLineOrBand.prototype, 'render', function (proceed) {
    var chart = this.axis.chart;

    proceed.call(this);

    if (!chart.seriesGroup) {
        chart.seriesGroup = chart.renderer.g('series-group')
            .attr({ zIndex: 3 })
            .add();
    }

    if (this.svgElem.parentGroup !== chart.seriesGroup) {
        this.svgElem
            .attr({ zIndex: this.options.zIndex })
            .add(chart.seriesGroup);
    }
    return this;
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'red',
            width: 2,
            value: 3.5,
            zIndex: 10
        }]
    },
    series: [{
        data: [7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227],
        zIndex: 9
    }, {
        data: [8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111],
        zIndex: 11
    }]
});
```

The code uses Torsteins plugin to allow the plotline in between series. See the GitHub issues for discussion on caveats and potential improvements.

Comment: That did exactly the trick! Thank you for the clear example! I never found that issue when searching, lol.